# $.getJSON is not working in another server

Tags: jquery, json

I am fetching a peculiar problem. $.getJSON is not working properly

```
$.getJSON('http://golfersapp.omaserver.com/courses.php?populate=country', function(listcountry1) {
         alert("golf server");//alert is not showing
        });
```

but below is running properly

```
$.getJSON('http://inveniya.net/jasmine-device/TenantList.php', function(data) {
                alert("inveniya");// it is showing properly
                });
```

Simply alerts is not coming!
Both are running from same page. one is running and another is not running. Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have tried checking `console.log(data)`?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a minor problem on the page which causes the data to be invalid JSON, see the last three lines of the page:

```
Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mobile\golfersapp\courses.php on line    100
Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mobile\golfersapp\courses.php on line 111
Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mobile\golfersapp\courses.php on line 137
```

You should fix these notices to get valid JSON.

Answer (score 3):

You are violating the [`same origin policy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction by attempting to send a cross domain AJAX request.

This can only work if the remote server (domain) supports `JSONP` which doesn't seem to be the case. Navigating at `http://golfersapp.omaserver.com/courses.php?populate=country` simply returns `JSON`, not `JSONP`.